# How to count function calls using decorators?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm refreshing my memory about some python features that I didn't get yet, I'm learning from [this python tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php) and there's an example that I don't fully understand. It's about a decorator counting calls to a function, here's the code:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(x):
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0
    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(succ.calls)
    for i in range(10):
        print(succ(i))
    print(succ.calls)
```

What I don't get here is why do we increment the calls of the function wrapper (helper.calls += 1) instead of the function calls itself, and why does it actually working?

Comment: `@call_counter succ` == `succ = call_counter(succ) = helper`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important thing to remember about decorators is that a decorator is a *function* that takes a function as an argument, and returns yet another function. The returned value - yet another function - is what will be called when the name of the original function is invoked.

This model can be very simple:

```
def my_decorator(fn):
    print("Decorator was called")
    return fn
```

In this case, the returned function is the same as the passed-in function. But that's usually not what you do. Usually, you return either a completely different function, or you return a function that somehow chains or wraps the original function.

In your example, which is a very common model, you have an inner function that is returned:

```
def helper(x):
    helper.calls += 1
    return func(x)
```

This inner function calls the original function (`return func(x)`) but it also increments the calls counter.

This inner function is being inserted as a "replacement" for whatever function is being decorated. So when your module `foo.succ()` function is looked up, the result is a reference to the inner helper function returned by the decorator. That function increments the call counter and then calls the originally-defined `succ` function.

Answer (score 5):

When you decorate a function you "substitute" you're function with the wrapper.

In this example, after the decoration, when you call `succ` you are actually calling `helper`. So if you are counting calls you have to increase the `helper` calls.

You can check that once you decorate a function the name is binded tho the wrapper by checking the attribute _*name*_ of the decorated function:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        helper.calls += 1
        print(helper.calls)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    helper.calls = 0
    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

succ(0)
>>> 1
succ(1)
>>> 2
print(succ.__name__)
>>> 'helper'
print(succ.calls)
>>> 2
```

Comment: I believe `**args` should actually be `**kwargs` as in key word arguments.

Comment: I am doing a logger decorator. Is there a way to know how many levels its inside if, lets say, decorated func A calls decorated func B, to have a variable that tells me func A is level 1 and func B is level 2?

Answer (score 4):

### Example with Class Decorator

When you decorate a function with the **Class Decorator**, every function has its own call_count. This is simplicity of **OOP**. Every time ***CallCountDecorator*** object is called, it will increase its own **call_count** attribute and print it.

```
class CallCountDecorator:
    """
    A decorator that will count and print how many times the decorated function was called
    """

    def __init__(self, inline_func):
        self.call_count = 0
        self.inline_func = inline_func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.call_count += 1
        self._print_call_count()
        return self.inline_func(*args, **kwargs)

    def _print_call_count(self):
        print(f"The {self.inline_func.__name__} called {self.call_count} times")


@CallCountDecorator
def function():
    pass


@CallCountDecorator
def function2(a, b):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
    function2(1, b=2)
    function()
    function2(a=2, b=3)
    function2(0, 1)

# OUTPUT
# --------------
# The function called 1 times
# The function2 called 1 times
# The function called 2 times
# The function2 called 2 times
# The function2 called 3 times
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand this (correct me if I'm wrong) the order you program executes is:

1. Register `call_counter`.
2. Register `succ`.
3. While registering `succ` function interpreter finds a decorator so it executes `call_counter`.
4. Your function returns an object which is a function (`helper`). And adds to this object field `calls`.
5. **Now your function `succ` has been assigned to `helper`**. So when you call your function, you're actually calling `helper` function, wrapped within a decorator. So every field you add to your helper function is accessible outside by addressing `succ` because those 2 variables refer to same thing.
6. So when you call `succ()` it's basically the same if you would do `helper(*args, **argv)`

Check this out:

```
def helper(x):
    helper.calls += 1
    return 2
helper.calls = 0

def call_counter(func):
    return helper

@call_counter
def succ(x):
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(succ == helper)  # prints true.
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't get here is why do we increment the calls of the function wrapper (helper.calls += 1) instead of the function calls itself, and why does it actually working?

I think to make it a generically useful decorator. You could do this

```
def succ(x):
    succ.calls += 1
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    succ.calls = 0
    print(succ.calls)
    for i in range(10):
        print(succ(i))
    print(succ.calls)
```

which works just fine, but you would need to put the `.calls +=1` in every function you wanted to apply this too, and initialise to 0 before you ran any of them. If you had a whole bunch of functions you wanted to count this is definitely nicer. Plus it initialises them to 0 at definition, which is nice.

As i understand it it works because it replaces the function `succ` with the `helper` function from within the decorator (which is redefined every time it decorates a function) so `succ = helper` and `succ.calls = helper.calls`. (although of course the name helper is only definied within the namespace of the decorator)

Does that make sense?