# Monitoring function calls in packages

Tags: python, code-coverage, usage-statistics

Is there a way to monitor which functions and methods in a directory of Python packages get called?  I'm working with a large library of custom Python modules, and for code cleanup purposes I'm curious how many of the functions are actually being used.

I know I can see what code is run from a given command using [Coverage.py](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but I want to know how the code is used in the real world.  If no one is calling the script that calls `foo`, I'd prefer to get rid of `foo` instead of maintaining it.

I would prefer a solution with low overhead, so as to not impact the runtime of the modules.

Comment: Are you able to edit the code that you'd like to monitor?

Comment: Yes. It would be nice if the solution could be separate from the code, but not essential

Comment: Not a dupe, but the answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968004/python-decorators-count-function-call. Make a decorator that counts calls and then runs the function normally.

Comment: Why not use coverage.py while the code is running in the real world?

Comment: @NedBatchelder are you suggesting setting up the `python` command as a wrapper so that every Python script call actually runs the script in `coverage`?

Comment: @jpyams I don't know how you are running your program in production.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I guess `Coverage.py` would work if the overhead is low. I don't know what it's overhead is